# Node comparison for hierarchical tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, comparison, hierarchical

I have an algorithm to classify some websites on a hierarchical tree. But I have trouble to test on the algorithm. Say the result suppose to be at one node, but the algorithm give me a different node, how do I measure the difference between the two node.

More specifically, I have an algorithm to categorize webpage to a hierarchical category. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/ is under computer>development>development Q&A. I am trying to test how the algorithm works. And trying to come up with a way to compare two nodes on a built tree.

I have some ideas now: 1. Calculate the distance of the two nodes. 2. Get the path of two node, as two lists and compare the lists.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? As the question is currently worded, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the algorithm giving you a different node. Are you trying to measure the distance between two nodes in a tree? Or the difference between two trees? Or something else?